# Run multiple line as a single line command bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Is there any way to run multiple line as a single line command in bash script.

This is my multiple line bash script

```
id=15;
if [ $id -ge 30 ]
then
echo Successful
echo $id
else
echo fail
echo $id
fi
```

I want to run this multiple line as a single line so far i have tried this way

```
id=15;if [ $id -ge 30 ]&&then&&echo Successful&&echo $id&&else&&echo fail&&echo $id&&fi
```

but when I executed this command in terminal i got this error

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Any idea how to change multiple line script to a single line command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you could replace the `&&` with `;` which is equivalent to the line breaks in your multiple-line code. Secondly I don't think you need the `&&` (or `;`) after the `then` statement.

The difference between the `&&` and `;` line breaks is that `&&` will run the next block of code if and only if the previous block has executed properly.

Comment: Like this right `id=15; if [ $id -ge 30 ]; then echo Successful; echo $id; else echo fail; echo $id; fi` thanks it worked

Comment: @Eka exactly. Glad I could help.